# One value should have respective another value, Repeating value should be notified in array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in php as shown below

```
$Uni_Order_Cus_No = array();
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
$Uni_Order_Cus_No [] = $order_no.$customer_id; 
}
```

which yields below result which is totally fine.

```
Array ( [0] => PO-2018-11TEST1 [1] => PO-2018-11TEST1 [2] => PO-2018-025TEST1 [3] => PO-2018-025TEST1 ).
```

Now i need to display an error message when the output is somewhat like this

```
Array ( [0] => PO-2018-11TEST1 [1] => PO-2018-11ABC [2] => PO-2018-025TEST1 [3] => PO-2018-025TEST1 ).
```

The actual scenario behind it is One **$Order_no** should have only one **$Customer_No**.

I tried with

```
if (count ( array_unique ( $Uni_Order_Cus_No ) ) >=  count ( $Uni_Order_Cus_No ))
{}
```

But am not able to get desired result. Any help Appreciated

Comment: _But am not able to get desired result._ What errors do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error, I want the logic so that i can display a alert message

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to return an array which counts the number of occurrences. Then use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if there is a value of 1 which means that there were 2 different values.

```
$Uni_Order_Cus_No = [
    "PO-2018-11TEST1",
    "PO-2018-11TEST1",
    "PO-2018-025TEST1",
    "PO-2018-025TEST1",
];
if (in_array(1, array_count_values($Uni_Order_Cus_No), true)) {
    echo "error message";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/S516D)